# Run other scripts called in a script in interactive mode

Tags: bash, shell

**TLDR**

```
$ docker ps 
Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.19/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?

$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

$ alias docker="sudo docker"

$ cat script1.sh
docker ps
./script2.sh

$ cat script2.sh
docker image ls

$ bash -i script1.sh  # call in interactive mode so that aliases could expand 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.19/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

How do I make other scripts called by the first script also run in interactive mode ***without actually changing the scripts***?
The reason for not changing the scripts is that there are a lot of nested scripts that I am only trying to run on my workstation. I want to stop the hassle of changing them everytime and reverting before doing a `git commit`.

---

**Use case**
There are several use cases when I need to run scripts where some commands need sudo to work in my workspace. And so I am searching for a way to make them run without directly editting the scripts to append sudo before those commands (as the script calls a lot of other scripts).

To name a few:

- A script with 'anything docker' won't work unless I run it with sudo. I know I can add the user to docker group to make it work.
- Another example would be when a few scripts need python with sudo (despite being a bad practice, the reason being a few limitations of not being able to change default python version in Centos6).

One way I can think of to make this work would be to make script use aliases, but as the aliases work only when the shell is interactive, it won't work if another script is called in the called script.
I am welcome for any other ideas, given the scripts remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

script1.sh

```sh
alias docker="sudo docker"
docker ps
```

script2.sh

```sh
. ./script1.sh # assumes sript1/script2 are in same dir
docker image ls
```

```sh
> bash -i script2.sh
```

If you have more complex requirements than this, feel free to throw them in and I can make another suggestion.

Comment: Edited the response .. is this better? Are you looking for a generic way to add a dependency from one script on to another? Is there a specific problem you're having besides getting docker run via `sudo`

Comment: Please read the complete question. This is a generic thing, not completely docker specific. And the scripts above are just samples here. The real ones calls a lot of different ones and I don't want to trace and change all of them.

Comment: The only real suggestion without investing significant time into this I can make is to look at using the `xargs` command ... it *might* do what you want. I'll delete this answer shortly to save myself from being down voted